# EF generic repository to any data provider

Tags: c#, orm, repository-pattern, n-tier-architecture

I'm trying to make my `EF` generic repository more "wide" to work with any data provider(ORM) like EF, NHibernate, Amazon Services  and so on without any binding to `EF` context.

For now I have(gist links):

- [IRepository](https://gist.github.com/maksii/5150366)
- [Repository](https://gist.github.com/maksii/5150372)

I'm have rewrite [IRepository](https://gist.github.com/maksii/5150401) and part of [Repository](https://gist.github.com/maksii/5150410).

But dunno what to do with `EF` and how finally get rid of it.

Can you give me some articles or code samples to get the right direction in my work.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of IRepository id to make **different implementation for each ORM** in the Repository. That way you don't have to build your solution depending on the ORM itself.

Then I think you're making it wrong when you try to make your repository to deal with many ORM's

***Update:***

You should build your BLL depending on IRepository without knowing anything about the implementation then you may use Constructor Injection or Dependency Resolver to pass the suitable implementation to the BLL.

E.G.

```
public interface IProductRepository{
   void AddProduct(Product model);
   void UpdateProduct(Product model);
}
```

EF implementation :

```
public class ProductRpository : IProductRepository
{
   void AddProduct(Product model)
   {
      //Add any code you want maybe EF code.
   }
   void UpdateProduct(Product model)
   {
      //........
   }
}
```

Then in the BLL you depend on IProductRepository ont on ProductRepository :

```
public class ProductService
{
   private readonly IProductRepository repository
   public ProductService(IProductRepository repository){
      this.repository = repository
   }
// ........ the code of your BLL
}
```

Comment: So i need EfRepository, NhRepository and so on? How i'll call it in my BLL if i'll need ef and nhibernate at the same time? Now i just use https://gist.github.com/maksii/5150547

Comment: @MaksMartynov Look to my Update :)